# Xcode 6 IDE: How to close GIT panel beside code editor?

Tags: xcode, xcode6.1

Using Xcode 6.1 I opened a panel showing GIT commit notes somehow and now I would like to close it. Does anyone know how???

[image]

Comment: Right clicking on it, digging through the view menu, google searches with terms like "xcode 6 close git panel"

Answer (score 57):

Found it at http://natashatherobot.com/git-blame-view-xcode/ It's called the "blame view" and you close it by clicking on the "One view" editor button at the top of the window (just to the right of the text "Today at 10:18 AM" in the image above.)

On Yosemite, this is what the button should look like:

[image]